# How to convert 'int*' to 'int^' in C++/CLI?

Tags: c++-cli, managed-c++

I want to wrap a c++ pointer field to property in CLI, here is my code:

```
class NativeClass
{
public:
    int* nativeApointer;
}

ref class ManagedClass
{
    NativeClass* thisClass
    property int^ A
    {
        int^ get()
        {
            return thisClass->nativeApointer
        }
    }
}
```

compiler noticed errror, so how did convert unmanaged pointer to interior pointer?

Comment: .NET properties use getter/setter rather than returning a writable reference (upcoming C# version *may* change this, finally).  So why not `get() { return *nativepointer; } set(int newvalue) { *nativepointer = newvalue; }`

Comment: And basically you should *never* see the type `int^`.  `int` is a value type, so it is normally just `int`, and a byref parameter is `int%`, and combining it with `^` is weird strongly-typed boxed value that is incompatible with all other .NET languages.

Comment: @BenVoigt ref returns are in the C# language already ;) @cook you *can* expose a native pointer of type `int*`, but unless this points to an array of ints, you should rather expose a property with a get/set pair over a simple `int`.